# Labeling polygons along their boundaries using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, labeling, line, borders

When labeling polygons (not polylines!) in QGIS, is it possible to label them along their borders rather than their area?

I know I could convert polygons to polylines and then label them, but I am looking for a solution, where I would only label a specific selection of polygons from a polygon shapefile, therefore I would like to keep them in the same shapefile (i.e. the same shape).

Below is the example of a desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes you can.

Go to 'layer properties' > 'labels'

Under 'placement' choose 'Using perimeter'

[image]